# Copy from vector<pointer*> to vector<pointer*> in C++

Tags: c++, stdvector

I create a vector A and want to copy to a vector B in another class by using below method, is it a correct way? The vector A may be destroyed! I searched in google, but not found the good solution and meaningful explanation. Thanks everyone

```
void  StateInit(vector<CButton*> listBtn) 
{ 
   _m_pListBtn = listBtn; 
 };
```

Comment: Yes, that looks correct... As long as you remember that two pointers can point to the same object.

Comment: Better to write your function `void  StateInit(const vector<CButton*>& listBtn)`. The way it's written now the vector will be copied twice, once to `listBtn` and again to `_m_pListBtn`. No point in that.

Comment: @john and Beta however the vector A will be able to destroyed in future, will it make the null exception when we accessing in B ? If not, I guess because we do '_m_pListBtn = listBtn;' it only copies all the elements in listBtn to _m_pListBtn, it doesn't copy the pointer of vector A to vector B ??? I'm a new guy in C++, sry for some silly question ^^

Comment: Does the vector listBtn only a copy of Vector A ? Only all the addresses of elements in vector A will be pointed to ?

Comment: It's quite simple. Copying the vector does copy the pointers. If you destroy the pointer in one vector you won't be able to use the pointer in the other vector. But destroying the vector does not destroy the pointer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes and no, you are passing the vector by value:

```
void  StateInit(vector<CButton*> listBtn) 
{ 
   _m_pListBtn = listBtn; 
 };
```

Wich means that listBtn is a copy of vector A (asuming we are calling vector A the one passed as parameter of StateInit), if you delete vector A, vector B will still have the collection of pointers and they will be valid since the destruction of a vector of pointers doesnt delete the pointed objects because it cant possible now how (should it call, delete, delete[], free?).

Do keep in mind that if you modify/delete one of the elements from vector A (using the pointers on the vector), that element will be modified in vector B (since its a pointer to the same element).

Im not sure what is your intend with this, but if you want to copy the whole vector, you should implement a clone mechanism for the objects and then copy them using transform:

```
class cloneFunctor {
public:
    T* operator() (T* a) {
        return a->clone();
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
void  StateInit(vector<CButton*> listBtn) 
{ 
   transform(listBtn.begin(), listBtn.end(), back_inserter(_m_pListBtn), cloneFunctor()); 
 };
```

IF your intention is not to clone it but to share the pointers you should pass the vector as pointer or reference:

```
void StateInit(const vector<CButton*>& listBtn) 
{ 
   _m_pListBtn = listBtn; 
};
```

Answer (score -3):

A better way is to iterate on the new vector and `push_back` the elements to your vector.

See example code: [std::vector::begin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/begin/)