# Does push_back in vector insert at the same location?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

```
class Example
{
    public: int i;
    Example(const Example &e)
    {
        i = e.i;
    }
    Example(int i)
    {
        this->i = i;
    }
};

int main()
{
std::vector<Example*> vec;
std::vector<Example*> newVec;

Example* ex1 = new Example(1);
Example* ex2 = new Example(2);

vec.push_back(ex1);
vec.push_back(ex2);

//newVec = vec; --> This does shallow copy

for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) // --> Deep copy
{
    Example newE(*(vec[i]));
    newVec.push_back(&newE);
}

for(int i=0; i<newVec.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "\nfoobar" << newVec[i]->i << "\n";
}
}
```

The above code prints foobar2 twice. Shouldn't it print foobar1 and foobar2? Also, is this the best way to copy a vector containing objects? I want deep copying.

Comment: `newVec.push_back(&newE);`  pushes a pointer to a local variable that gets out of scope immediately making it a dangling pointer.

Comment: ...so from that point, anything can happen. Accessing that pointer can return random stuff, abort the program with a segmentation fault, or order pizzas.

Comment: Your vectors don't contain objects, they contain pointers. Use vectors with objects for a more comfortable life.

Comment: So, how do I make deep copy of the vector vec with pointers to objects?

Comment: This is generally a very non-cpp approach you are taking. Given your example most people would likely not write a vector of pointers to class, but a vector of structs, which then is deep-copied when a copy is required, passed around as `const &` when it is read only, or moved when it is returned or otherwise passed around in any way where one instance should take over the content of another.

Comment: Thanks, all. Let us say I can't change how things are already implemented. To make a vector of pointers to deep copied objects using transform function is one approach I read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475042/copy-from-vectorpointer-to-vectorpointer-in-c. 
Is it a bad approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) // --> Deep copy
> {
>     Example newE(*(vec[i]));
>     newVec.push_back(&newE);
> }
> ```

In this code you make a copy of `vec[i]` to `Example newE`. Then you `push_back` the *address* of `newE` to the `newVec` vector. Then the `newE` object goes out of scope and is destroyed, so you end up having a pointer to garbage inside `newVec`.

If you want a deep copy of vector content, *and* you want to store owning pointers to objects, consider using **vector of smart pointers**, e.g. `vector<shared_ptr<Example>>`.

In this case, you can simply copy the vectors with `operator=`, and the reference counts of the `shared_ptr`s will be *automatically* updated.

Yoy may want to consider also the simpler design of just having `vector<Example>` (without pointer indirection).

Comment: Thanks. Let us say I can't change how things are already implemented. To make a vector of pointers to deep copied objects using transform function is one approach I read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475042/copy-from-vectorpointer-to-vectorpointer-in-c. 
Is it a bad approach?

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not correct and results in undefined behavior.

This loop is problematic:

```
for(int i=0; i<vec.size(); ++i) // --> Deep copy
{
    Example newE(*(vec[i]));
    newVec.push_back(&newE);
}
```

You declare a local variable `newE`. Such variable has automatic storage duration (often referred as stack allocated, although the C++ standard technically does not require a stack to be used to implement them).

Variables with automatic storage duration have the following properties:

- Their lifetime start at the point they are declared.
- Their lifetime end at the **end of the scope** they are declared in.

Each iteration of your `for` loop is a scope, so after the first iteration, `newE` is not valid anymore and the compiler is free to generate instructions that will reuse the memory.

This is exactly what happen in your case (and in any decent implementation): each iteration will place `newE` at the exact same address.

But, as you used `operator&` to take the address of `newE`, and `newE` then goes out of scope, you now have a **dangling pointer**.

Dangling pointers by themselves are not problematic, but you can't do anything really meaningful with them. In particular, dereferencing one results in **undefined behavior**.

---

You have multiple ways to fix your code.

The easy way would be using `new`:

```
Example* newE = new Example(*vec[i]);
newVec.push_back(newE);
```

But you would then have to make sure to add the appropriates `delete` too. Also, this is not really pedantic C++.

Another way would be to change `vec` and `newVec` to `std::vector<Example>`, to sidestep the raw pointers issues. This would be the preferred way to express your code in C++.

In some cases you need the pointers, if you do polymorphism for example. Then, you may use `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` to have pointer semantics and RAII.

Answer (score 2):

```
Example newE(*(vec[i]));
newVec.push_back(&newE);
```

allocates `newE` on the stack, then pushes a pointer to it into the vector. `newE` goes out of scope at the end of the loop iteration, and you just go lucky that the location of `newE` is not reused. It seems the compiler generated code that puts both stack-instances in the same place, so you overwrite that location with the second value, then you de-reference that location twice, when iterating over the vector of **pointers**.